# Collider won't trigger if my player isn't moving in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

PLAYER = Ninja Boy
ENEMY = Ninja girl

I have two game objects, one is enemy and the other is player both having colliders2D and rigidbody2D.
I made a script for enemy chase my when i;m in his sight(i made a boxcollider2d for this) and when he's close enought he start's attacking. To detect collision between he's sword and me i made an edge collider that he enables it when starts attacking and disable when the attack animation is done
[image: here is the enemy with the sword collider]

The problem is that when i don't move, the player OnEnterTrigger2D function doesn't detect the collision
if i'm in this position (the player is clearly inside the collider) 
[image]

This is the Player class

```
    public override IEnumerator TakeDamage()
    {
        if (!immortal && !IsDead) 
        {
            health -= 10;
            Animator.SetLayerWeight(1, 0);

            if (!IsDead)
            {
                Animator.SetTrigger("damage");
                Rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                immortal = true;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(immortalTimer);
                immortal = false;
            }
        }

        if(IsDead)
        {
            Animator.SetTrigger("dead");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        Debug.Log(collider.name);
        base.OnTriggerEnter2D(collider);
    }
```

and the player inherits from Character

```
public abstract IEnumerator TakeDamage();

  protected virtual void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (damagingObjects.Contains(collider.tag))
        {
            StartCoroutine(TakeDamage());
        }
    }
```

and i noticed that if a manualy activate the enemy's trigger while playing, the player will take damege even if he's not moving

Comment: Maybe `OnTriggerStay2D` will help you. You'll want a boolean to track if you've already detected the overlap, and maybe reset the boolean in `OnDisable` or something.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried OnTriggerStay2D, OnCollisionStay2D, OnCollisionEnter2D but I still have to move for them to detect collision